# GROUP BY and JOIN on a 3 hour increment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables - one that has one record for every 3 hours:

```
    a.aDT        a.aVal
------------    -----------
8/10/15 00:00   1550
8/10/15 03:00   1600
8/10/15 06:00   1650
```

I have second table that has a value every minute:

```
b.bDT           b.bVal
--------      ------------
8/10/15 00:00     1
8/10/15 00:01     1
8/10/15 00:02     0
```

I need to wind up with a query that has the value/datetime from the 3 hour sample (a.aDT, a.aVal) in two columns, and the sum of the values from b (b.bVal) in the third column. I've tried GROUP BY (DATEPART(HOUR,bDT) % 3) but that doesn't seem to return what I'm looking for.

Thoughts?

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: You were close. Try `datepart(hour, bDT) / 3`.

Answer (score 3):

The following will round your seconds values up to the nearest three-hour interval.  For example, values between 9:00 and 11:59 will be rounded to the 12:00 sample, and values between 12:00 and 14:59 will be rounded to the 15:00 sample.  Depending on how you want to handle values occurring exactly on your cutoffs, you may want to adjust them slightly.

For example, if you want values occurring at 3:00 exactly to be in the 3:00 group, rather than the 6:00 group, you should subtract a second from your bDt before using the logic below.

```
Select a.aDT, a.aVal, sum(b.bVal)
from TableA a
left join TableB b
on datepart(HH, a.aDT) 
    = (datepart(HH, b.bDt) - datepart(HH, bDt) % 3 + 3) % 24 --Convert the time in table B to be the next highest multiple of three
and cast(a.aDt as date) 
    = cast(b.bDt as date) --Make sure the samples are from the same day
group by a.aDT, a.aVal
```

Comment: I've got a data issue I need to run down, but I think you've got it. Once I double check it, I'll green check mark it. THANKS!

Comment: OK, brilliantly elegant... except, on the midnight values, I'm getting NULL on the sum.

Comment: @Ell thanks for the feedback! I have added `% 24` to convert values between 9 pm and midnight to hour 0 instead of hour 24.  Let me know if this works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @DATA TABLE (bDT DATETIME, bVal INT)

INSERT INTO @DATA (bDT, bVal)
SELECT '2015-08-10 00:00', 1 UNION
SELECT '2015-08-10 00:01', 1 UNION
SELECT '2015-08-10 00:02', 0 UNION
SELECT '2015-08-10 03:00', 1 UNION
SELECT '2015-08-10 04:00', 1 UNION
SELECT '2015-08-10 06:15', 0 UNION
SELECT '2015-08-10 06:15', 1 

SELECT *, DATEADD(HH,(DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(TIME,bDT))/3)*3, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,bDT))) Matching_A_Hour
FROM @DATA

SELECT DATEADD(HH,(DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(TIME,bDT))/3)*3, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,bDT))) Matching_A_Hour, SUM(bVal)
FROM @DATA
GROUP BY DATEADD(HH,(DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(TIME,bDT))/3)*3, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,bDT)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select a.aDT ,
       a.aVal,
       (select sum(b.bVal) from table2 b where b.bDT between a.aDT and dateadd(hh,3,a.aDT) )
from table1 a
```

sum between three hour